# View a list of all schema in a PostgreSQL database in r?

Tags: r, dplyr, rpostgresql

I'm connecting and querying a PostgreSQL database through the `dplyr` package in R. I know I can list all the tables in the database using `dbListTables(con)`.
But, my tables are organized into different schema. What is the easiest way I can view all of the schema that are present in my database using R?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT nspname FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace")`